# Temporary Skip frequency on an Icom ID-51 PLUS2

Tags: icom, equipment-operation, icom-id-51-plus2

On the scanning options for the Icom ID-51 PLUS2, there's one called Temporary Skip Timer that can be any of:

- 5 minutes
- 10 minutes
- 15 minutes

The manual says:

> Temporary Skip Timer
>
> Selects the Temporary Skip Time. When the time is set, specified frequencies are skipped for this period during a scan.

So, it sounds like you can temporary skip a frequency while scanning, to not be bothered by persistent interference in a single frequency. Is that correct? If so, how do you do it? How do you actually skip a frequency? I can't find it on the manual.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your presumption about how it functions is correct. The skip time is a global setting for all timed skip operations. It is set from the main Menu.

If you wish to skip a channel for the timed period set from the main menu, when the scan stops on the desired frequency, press the Quick key. Then use the up/down arrows to select Temporary Skip. Finally press the Enter key. That channel will then be skipped for the programmed time.

Note that there are two user manuals for this radio. In the US English version of the **advanced** manual (A-7331-3EX), see pages 13-13 and 16-18 for the details.

Comment: Oh... there's another manual? I was wondering whether that was the case because the one in the box didn't cover many options. I'll get it and read it next then.